# How to detect direct visit to website via PHP

Tags: php

I'm interested how can I detect a source of the visit - is it a direct link, via referrer or via search engine, and using PHP?

More concise, when someone access my website by directly typing the http://ww.mysite.com in their browser, how can I detect such visitors (using PHP)?

Comment: you check the http referer, and realize that it's not 100% reliable or accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each request has a referer, i.e. a URL which the user came from. PHP provides this information in the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable.

If a user accessed your website directly, i.e. via direct type-in or a bookmark, the referer is empty.

Note that some browser add-ons and “security software” will remove the referer for privacy reasons.

But if it's just for statistical purposes, you may assume that the referer is valid in 99.9% of all page views.

But remember: The referer can easily be forged to contain any value the visitor wants it to be. Including malicious code like XSS or SQL injection. Be careful when processing it.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. One more thing:
if a user comes to a certain page of the website directly, the referrer is empty, yes (in the context of those assumptions)?

But when he navigates further through the site, is the refferer for each following page empty as well or is it set to the previous page?

Example: visitor comes directly to the homepage. The referrer is empty. Then he clicks on the internal link a, and goes to mysite.com/a/ -> what's the referrer to that page? Empty or mysite.com?

Comment: Exactly. If a user navigates further through the site, the referer will always contain the page he visited *just before*.

Comment: If you need to grab the “original” referer, simply store it in a session cookie. On subsequent requests, you can read the value from the session.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know for sure, but `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is not set, then it is likely to be a direct visit.  You can also add parameters to links that you use in advertising to help you track the source, for example you might place adverts with links to example.com/?source=my-advertising-campaign

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: why -1 i dont understand?

Comment: Because there's no explaination. Especially there's no mention of the fact that the referer is empty if it was a direct type in (which is an essential aspect of the OP's question).

Comment: Yes it's always good to add an explanation for why this would work. Teach a man to fish and all that jazz. Fix the issue as your question is in the Review queue at the moment for being low quality.